# Lives counter in Python turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I could do with some help on how to make a lives counter in Python turtle graphics.

My code:

```
def draw_lives():

    global lives

    lives = turtle.Turtle()
    lives.penup
    lives.hideturtle
    lives.goto(-200, 400)

    while True:
        lives.write("Lives: " + str(lives), font=("Arial", 50, "normal"))
        if lives > 0:
        lives.write("You have lost all lives. Try again.", font=("Arial", 50, "normal"))
        break
```

I thought on making my lives counter a Turtle and not just a random counter somewhere (which would actually sound better).

Furthermore did I get the error for my `if lives > 0:` that the `>` is not supported between instances of `Turtle` and `int`.

Can someone help?

Comment: `lives` is a turtle object, you probably want a variable containing a number of lives remaining in that comparison

Comment: Are you confused as to *why the error occurs*? Or what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is badly constructed -- let's look at specifics.  The primary issue is that you use the same variable name, `lives`, for *both* the *counter* and the *turtle* that displays the counter.  Name them differently.  If you do so, you don't need:

```
global lives
```

The next problem is basic Python:

```
lives.penup
lives.hideturtle
```

These are method calls so they should be:

```
lives.penup()
lives.hideturtle()
```

Finally your `while True:` has no business here, or anywere in a turtle event-driven program.  And you're missing a line of code or two in your `if` statement.

Let's rework your code so that it updates the value of the `lives` counter on the screen:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT = ("Arial", 24, "normal")

def draw_lives():
    lives_pen.clear()

    if lives > 0:
        lives_pen.write("Lives: " + str(lives), font=FONT)
    else:
        lives_pen.write("You have lost all lives. Try again.", font=FONT)

lives = 5

lives_pen = Turtle()  # this turtle is only used to update lives counter display
lives_pen.hideturtle()
lives_pen.penup()
lives_pen.goto(-200, 300)
lives_pen.write("Lives: " + str(lives), font=FONT)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from time import sleep

    # test code

    screen = Screen()

    for _ in range(lives + 1):
        draw_lives()
        sleep(1)
        lives -= 1

    screen.exitonclick()
```

The `__main__` section is just test code to confirm that `draw_lives()` works the way we want -- so toss it.

Utility turtles like `lives_pen` should only be created *once*, not every time you need to update the counter as they are global entities and are not garbage collected when the function exits.

Comment: Cheers, that does look way better. Sorry for my inexperience literally started programming a few weeks ago.

Comment: One question though, since this skript seems to write "Lives: " twice. Once where i want it to be and once right in the middle

Comment: @HandsomeBanana, it doesn't behave as you describe when I run it and it shouldn't as it clearly moves the turtle away from the origin before writing anything.

Answer (score 0):

[It's a bad practice to use `global` in your code.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/13552470) Instead, you can create a custom attribute for your turtles.

It's super easy, barely an inconvenience:

```
from turtle import Turtle
pen = Turtle()
pen.lives = 5 # Here, the lives attribute is created
```

You may even do the same for the font, though it may be unnecessary:

```
pen.font = ("Arial", 30, "normal")
```

If loosing lives is the only situation where the life count will be updated, do not keep rewriting them in the loop
*(unless, of course, the something gets in the way of the text, and you want the text to be displayed on top)*,
only rewrite it when a life is lost.

We can redraw *and* update the lives in a function like this:

```
def update_lives():
    pen.clear()
    if pen.lives:
        pen.write(f"Lives: {pen.lives}", font=pen.font)
    else:
        pen.write("You have lost all lives. Try again.", font=pen.font)
    pen.lives -= 1 # Remove this line and this becomes your typical text updater
```

To see this in action, I implemented a demo where a life is lost whenever the user presses the SPACE bar:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

wn = Screen()

def update_lives():
    pen.clear()
    if pen.lives:
        pen.write(f"Lives: {pen.lives}", font=pen.font)
    else:
        pen.write("You have lost all lives. Try again.", font=pen.font)
    pen.lives -= 1

pen = Turtle(visible=False)
pen.penup()
pen.goto(-300, 200)
pen.lives = 5
pen.font = ("Arial", 30, "normal")

update_lives()

wn.listen()
wn.onkey(update_lives, 'space')
```

With the above code, when the user reaches `0`, pressing SPACE again will make the function proceed to display negative values.

To fix that, for your main game loop, use `while pen.lives` to tell python to only keep looping until the number of lives remaining is greater than `0`:

```
while pen.lives:
    # Your game code here
    wn.update()
```

Output:

[image]